# Is there a way for ClickMajick to run on Wix and log button clicks aka 'cta'?

Tags: logging, velo, event-tracking

ClickMajick is not registering on my Wix page.

I added the below ClickMagick script to the Wix "custom code" under settings and placed it in the header. When I verify the page link.  It does not register.

Also I am trying to add a custom css to a button or picture with the value 'cta'. I think I got the 'cta' to work as it shows it in the debug log.  But I'd like to see how others are doing this.

```
<script>
    window.clickmagick_cmc = {
        uid: 'xxxxxx',
        hid: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        log_action:'.cta',
        cmc_project: 'NameXYZ',
        audopt_pro: 'on',
    }
</script>
<script src='//cdn.clkmc.com/cmc.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    window.clickmagick_cmc = {
        uid: '192373',
        hid: '931055034',
        cmc_project: 'xodub.com',
        vid_info: 'on',
        log_action: '.cta',
    }
</script>
<script src='//cdn.clkmc.com/cmc.js'></script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this will help solving the question asked.